# Using Azure SignalR with React Native app

Tags: react-native, signalr, azure-signalr

I've seen some code samples on how to use `SignalR` with `React Native` apps but haven't found any information about connecting a `React Native` app to the `Azure SignalR` service. Is this possible?

To clarify it further, I am using the [service version of `SignalR`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/) and NOT the hosted version.

Comment: You still need some server to put your's hub's logic in to. The Azure SignalR is for handling the connections, sessions, Redis and etc... When you are connected to your SignalR server, it will just redirect you to the Azure SignalR.

Comment: If you want serverless SignalR application you can read more about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-pt/blog/real-time-serverless-applications-with-the-signalr-service-bindings-in-azure-functions/

Comment: I do have an ASP.NET Core API app that handles that and this app is configured to use the Azure SignalR service. Are you then saying connecting my ReactNative mobile app to SignalR service is the same as connecting to SignalR hosted because the connection is ultimately to my hubs which are on my API app?

Comment: You always need a hub. But you can change the service mode. Read more about it here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/faq.md#what-is-the-meaning-of-service-mode-defaultserverlessclassic-how-can-i-choose

Comment: Yes, I realize that about hubs. I currently have a fully functional chat app that works on browsers. My concern is that the JavaScript client maybe different if the functionality is managed by the service. I’m now ready to create my mobile app and trying to see if ReactNative is a supported platform by the Azure SignalR service. I remember reading somewhere that only Xamarin clients were supported. Just want to make sure that’s not the case.